# Find the m by m square that contains the most "conflicting pairs"?

Tags: algorithm, sparse-matrix

There are two types of units on a 2d plane, green units (G) and red units (R). 
The plane is represented as an n by n matrix, each unit is represented as an element in the matrix.

A pair of two units is called a "conflicting pair" if the two are of different colours. The goal is to find the m by m submatrix that contains the most "conflicting pairs".

Example

```
[R R 0 0 0
 R R 0 0 0
 0 0 R R 0
 0 0 0 G G
 0 0 0 G G]
```

In the above 5 by 5 matrix, the "most conflicting" 3 by 3 submatrix is at the lower right corner, where there are two red units and four green units, which amounts to 8 conflicting pairs within the submatrix.

---

A naive solution will take O(m^2n^2) for iterating every element in every possible submatrix.
I also thought of using dynamic programming like the [Summed-area table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table) algorithm, the time complexity will then be O(n^2), which looks good since it's already O(n^2) for scanning each element once.

However the n by n matrix may be large and sparse and given in a sparse format (like CSR), in that case an O(n^2) algorithm may not be efficient. Any suggeststions on how do I do better for sparse matrices (and dense matrices)?

Comment: There must be missing constrains in the problem because the 5x5matrix contains the most conflicts. If it has to be a sub matrix with m < n, then the bottom rightmost 4x4 matrix contains the most conflicts. That given answer doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @chmike: As I see it, the task is to find the m×m submatrix with the most confilicting pairs for any given m, in this case 3.

Comment: @MOehm wouldn't a 4x4 matrix have more conflicting pairs than the 3x3 matrix suggested as answer ? It would contain 3R and 4G, instead of 2R and 4G. A 5x5 matrix would contain the maximum number of conflicting pairs

Comment: Yes, but the (constant) m is a given value: You are to find a 3×3 submatrix. In other words, m is part of the problem's input, not its output.

Comment: i don't think it could be optimized any further as there seems no relation between two adjacent elements in m*m matrix

Comment: @chmike yes, actually m is given as an input, the expected output of the problem is the location

Answer (score 0):

The answer is given by

```
idx = argmax SUM(X_r,m) * SUM(X_g,m)
```

where `SUM(X,m)` returns a matrix with the summation of units in each `m x m` window, `X_r` and `X_g` are the matrices with only red and green units enabled respectively, and `idx` is the `m x m` window with the largest number of conflicting nodes.

The question then becomes can `SUM(X,m)` be more efficiently calculated for sparse matrices. I think the answer is: *it really depends on the structure of `X` and the value of `m`*.

An obvious way to make use of the sparsity of `X` is to compute `SUM(X,m)` by using the identity

```
SUM(X,m) = transpose(SUM1d( transpose(SUM1d(X,m) ), m ))   (1)
```

where `SUM1d(X,m)` is the results of summing intervals of length `m` along rows of `X`. Clearly, `SUM1d` can be implemented in `O(n)` time for each row, and `O(n^2)` for the entire matrix, in a similar fashion to the Sum-Area-Table algorithm. This yields the same complexity `O(n^2)` for the entire algorithm. But that is rather uninteresting as it's the same runtime as a Sum-Area-Table algorithm.

What is interesting is asking whether `SUM1d(X,m)` can be implemented to take advantage of any sparsity of `X`. It's clear that `SUM1d` can be implemented to take full advantage of the sparsity of the input matrix; however, depending on the structure of `X` and the size of `m` the output matrix may not be sparse.

Assuming, `m` is much less than `n` then implementing `SUM1d(X,m)` as described in eq (1) above can be done in `O(nz_row)` time where `nz_row` is the max number of non-zero elements on any of the rows of `X`. Furthermore, `SUM1d(X,m)` will produce a sparse matrix, albeit with `O(m)` less sparsity. Since we assume `m` is much less than `n` this is still a sparse matrix and will still translate to efficiency gains.

Therefore, we should expect `O(n*nz_row)` for the first call to `SUM1d` in eq (1) and `O(n*m*nz_col)` for the second call to `SUM1d`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `k` non-empty cells (with `R` or `G`) then you can solve with time complexity `O(k^2)` (squeeze the matrix) because optimal submatrix has one non-empty cell on the border of the matrix.

Or time complexity maybe `O(k * (log n)^2)` if use two dimension sparse segments tree for getting sum on a rectangle.